# tempusdominus работа с группой input-ов

Tags: javascript, datepicker

При вводе времени - число исчезает...можно ли как то исправить??

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // настраиваю datetime pickers
  $("#datetimepickerbb").datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT',
    locale: 'ru'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="input-group date col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12" id="datetimepickerbb" data-target-input="nearest">
  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="timeDurationForPositionDays" value="0">
  <div class="input-group-append">
    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepickerbb" data_val="false" id="timeDurationForPositionTime" value="00:00">
  <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepickerbb" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так

```js
$("#datetimepickerbb").datetimepicker({
            format: 'LT',
            locale: 'ru'
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.0-alpha14/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 

<div class="m-0 d-flex col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-7">
  <div class="input-group mx-0 px-0">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="timeDurationForPositionDays" value="0">
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <div class="input-group-text" style="border-radius:inherit"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group date mx-0 px-0" id="datetimepickerbb" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input style="border-radius:inherit" type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepickerbb" data_val="false" id="timeDurationForPositionTime" value="00:00">
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepickerbb" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="TimeDuration" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```